# error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'char *' and 'char *') , using macro

Tags: c, macros

(EDIT: mising datatypes of t1, t2 not  missing anymore)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(a, b) a = ( a = a + b, b = a- b, a-b )

int main()
{
    char *names[] = {"Pat", "Bob", "Ted", NULL};
    char *t1 = names[1];
    char *t2 = names[2];

    printf("%d %d\n",t1,t2);
    SWAP(t1,t2);
    printf("%d %d\n",t1,t2);

}
```

I know other versions of swap that will work. However, i want to focus on this specific one just for a momment... i do not like to blindly type code. Can you help me please to better understand the source/reason of the error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and details. Read [ask]. And don't use a macro where a function will do as well.

Comment: @Olaf what is wrong with my question? Isn't it good enough? :(

Comment: Where are your datatypes for `t1` and `t2`?  (Maybe you wanted to use commas in the declarations instead of semicolons)

Comment: Your `printf` should be `printf("%s %s\n", t1, t2);` or `printf("%p %p\n", (void*)t1, (void*)t2);`.  `"%d"` is for `int`s.

Comment: There are more errors/problems in your code than lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different answers:

1. Don't try to use "tricky" swap macros.
2. You can't add pointers.

Taking these in turn:

1​. I know what that swap macro is trying to do, but, seriously, what's the advantage?  Just say

```
char *tmp = t1;
t1 = t2;
t2 = tmp;
```

Everybody knows what this means.  No trickery required.

In my opinion (some might disagree), there's no such thing as a good swap macro.  Every swap macro introduces more problems than it solves.

2​. Your "tricky" swap macro, although it might work for integers (and miiiiiiiiight work for floating point) does not work for pointers, and the reason it doesn't work is that C takes the point of view that it's meaningless to add a pointer to a pointer.  You can add an integer to a pointer, but you can't add two pointers.

Comment: "You can't add pointers".  I totally forgot that part (that it is not possible to add 2 pointers, silly me :(

Comment: Even for integers it might actually not always work because signed overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: @alain Right.  (That's why I said "might". :-) )